# WordPress thickbox responsive

Tags: wordpress, thickbox

I'm working on a WordPress plugin. I would like to use a kind of modal for this. I'have found the thickbox. This work well ! But, this is not responsive.

Do you have any idea to make this thickbox responsive ? I tried to give it a width auto and a height in "vh" but nothing.

This is my code :

```
  <div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
     <form action="#" method="post">
                      <label for="digisoft_clickToCall_lastnameClient">Votre nom :</label><br>
                      <input id="digisoft_clickToCall_lastnameClient" name="digisoft_clickToCall_lastnameClient"
                               type="text"/>
                      <label for="digisoft_clickToCall_firstnameClient">Votre prénom :</label><br>
                      <input id="digisoft_clickToCall_firstnameClient" name="digisoft_clickToCall_firstnameClient"
                               type="text"/>
                      <label for="digisoft_clickToCall_emailClient">Votre adresse mail :</label><br>
                      <input id="digisoft_clickToCall_emailClient" name="digisoft_clickToCall_emailClient"
                               type="email"/>
                      <label for="digisoft_clickToCall_numberClient">Votre numéro :</label><br>
                      <input id="digisoft_clickToCall_numberClient" name="digisoft_clickToCall_numberClient"
                               type="tel"/><br>

                      <input type="submit" class="btn-group button" value="Demander le rappel">

                    </form>
</div>

<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=500&inlineId=my-content-id" id="callnowbutton" style="font-size: 150%; color:white;" class="thickbox">'.$buttonText.'</a>';
```

Ty for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A working example would be helpful. Otherwise we can only point you to certain directions.

One way to make something 'responsive' really fast is via flexbox.
For example:

```
.YOUR__CONTAINER {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column; }
```

Helpful Link to flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank's for you response. How can i give you an exemple ? We need a WordPress website to test this plugin. I can give you the .zip if you want.